# Set Password Policy to 'Never Expire' using metadata

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile, metadata

I need to deploy profile with Password policy setting as 'Never Expire'.
I am not able to get it deploy, don't find the tag use to deploy password settings.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to utilize the [`ProfilePasswordPolicy`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm) metadata here.

> Represents a profile’s password policies. Profile password policies override org-wide password policies for that profile’s users.

The `passwordExpiration` is the field which determines the password policy on the profile, and a value of `0` is what reflects that the password never expires.

> Number of days until user passwords expire and must be changed. If set to 0, the password never expires. Valid values: 0, 30, 60, 90, 365.